# How are rocket launches scheduled?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, launch, rockets, artificial-satellite

With all the satellites and other objects already in space; how exactly are launches scheduled and coordinated? Is there some kind of clearinghouse? How do the mega constellations affect the scheduling?

Comment: There are similar questions here already but I don't know if they are duplicates. Here are a few but I think there are more... [Who/What is the international authority to assign/refuse orbit to a satellite/space-craft?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/5943/12102) and [How exactly are satellites drifted to slots in different orbital planes?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21690/12102) and [How satellite orbital vacancies are determined?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/40476/12102) There are several "slots" Q's about GEO orbits as well, but I don't think that's what you are interested in

Comment: also [For constellations of circular LEO satellites, are there allocations of available “slots” in altitudes?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19072/12102)

Comment: I didn’t realize, that there are so many similar questions

Comment: I read the questions and answers. They’re not similar. The first answer is straight false, it says that the ITU is responsible for that, which is certainly false. There must be an organization or a procedure for this.

Comment: Is this about _launch_ _schedule_ or about resulting _orbit_? Some agencies have a role in one and not the other.

Comment: @mike if you have found an answer to a question that is false, it's okay to leave a comment to the answer's author *underneath that answer* explaining why you feel their answer is incorrect. If you feel the issue is more subtle, then you can instead ask a follow-up question asking for clarification and explaining your position. The goal of SE is to work together to generate good answers to on-topic questions. If something needs to be explored further or an answer contains questionable information, then people generally work together to get to the bottom of it.

Comment: No the question is about the scheduling of the launches. More or less the following question is about the orbits. My understanding is that the windows are created by the orbits. Simply because the launching satellite cannot be allowed to collide with others on launch during transition to the destination orbit and on the destination orbit